# Cannot get expected result of str.expandtabs()

Tags: python, string

I tested str.expandtab() today, it seems the testing result is not as expected.
Take the below example, the string 'ihrianrnka' after '\n' was not printed.
Can anyone explain it?
TIA

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> str = 'a\tbio\tpojfknPIjer\tiojoanf\nihrianrnka\riahfi\tann'  
>>> print(str.expandtabs(10))  
a         bio       pojfknPIjer         iojoanf  
iahfi     ann
```

Comment: You have a carriage return (`\r`) in that string, which goes back to the start of the current line, so some of the text is overwriting previous text.  Print the `repr()` of the string, and you'll see that everything is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I totally forget the meaning of '\r' at the time.
Just put it here for reference
a carriage return which often means that the cursor should move to the leftmost column, while \n is a line feed which moves the cursor to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is actually not the `\n` or the string after it. The problem is the `\r` after `ihrianrnka`.

`\r` signifies a carriage return in Windows. This is a hold over from the days of DOS.

`\n` signifies a new line in Windows and Linux.

So in Linux you just need `\n` for a new line. For Windows the way the software internally works is `\r\n` but it will handle just a `\n` for the sake of compatibility. However, the `\r` is not handled gracefully.

To fix your string you need to do this:

```
str = 'a\tbio\tpojfknPIjer\tiojoanf\nihrianrnka\riahfi\tann'
str = str.replace("\r", "\n")
print(str.expandtabs(10))
```